# Qt C++ QWebView image quality

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I notice, that some image on webpage has bad quality (sharp corners, no anti-aliasing). I use Qt 4.7.4. This bug not found in Qt 4.8.0 RC1 (I've tested, all OK). How to remove this bug?

Update: examples
http://piccy.info/view3/2305599/c2991408a666393dd49bbcc938ad2f9f/ - Qt 4.7.4
http://piccy.info/view3/2305604/9ac2408088af261edef3b852c4127414/ - Qt 4.8.0 RC1

On webpage images in jpeg. Can I remove this effects?

Comment: Can you give an example of a publicly-reachable webpage that shows this effect, e.g. when used with http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/webkit-framecapture.html ?  Give us something to reproduce / demonstrate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's resolved in Qt 4.8.0 you have two options, upgrade to it either as the RC (which for a production app is risky)/ wait until 4.8 is production ready (soon-ish) or my personal favourite which is pull QtWebKit 2.2 into your development environment. It's not straight forward, but you'll find that it's doable.

Or backport the fix for it, which will be probably more difficult than integrating 2.2 into your build.